# ASP.NET MVC HttpPost async task not functioning correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a form in my actors page. Upon clicking the submit button, fields are validated and it should in theory submit, but it is not. I have tried renaming, creating a new function that intellisense suggests and my only ways of making this form to submit is either manually making the function go to _service.Add(actor); or by not going with the validation, but then if one of the required fields is not met, it throws an error in a different page, which is not ideal. I have no clue how to make this work, because the course, that I am recreating it from is able to do it just fine.

My code - controller:

```
namespace Cinema_World.Controllers
{
    public class ActorsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IActorsService _service;

        public ActorsController(IActorsService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var allActors = await _service.GetAll();
            return View(allActors);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,BirthYear,BirthPlace")] ActorModel actor)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) //when i use break-points, this part gets stepped into
            {// also this part
                return View(actor); //this part too
            } // and this is the final part, then it skips to the end and nothing happens in the browser
            _service.Add(actor);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
    }
}
```

My models:

```
namespace Cinema_World.Models
{
    public class ActorModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int ActorID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "First name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is a required field")]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "First name can be between 1 and 100 characters long!")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Middle name")]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "Middle name can be between 1 and 100 characters long!")]
        public string? MiddleName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name is a required field")]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "Last name can be between 1 and 100 characters long!")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Year of Birth")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Year of birth is a required field")]
        [Range(999,9999, ErrorMessage = "Input a year between 999 and 9999")]
        public int BirthYear { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Place of Birth")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Place of birth is a required field")]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "Name of the place can be between 1 and 100 characters long!")]
        public string BirthPlace { get; set; }

        public  List<Actor_CinematographyModel> Actors_Cinematography { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Code from my service that gets called, when form submit is successful.

```
namespace Cinema_World.Data.Services
{
    public class ActorsService : IActorsService
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public ActorsService(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void Add(ActorModel Actor)
        {
            _context.Actors.Add(Actor);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Delete(int ActorID)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<ActorModel>> GetAll()
        {
            var result = await _context.Actors.ToListAsync();
            return result;
        }

        public ActorModel GetById(int ActorID)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public ActorModel Update(int ActorID, ActorModel newActor)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Interface for this specific service:

```
namespace Cinema_World.Data.Services
{
    public interface IActorsService
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<ActorModel>> GetAll();
        ActorModel GetById(int ActorID);
        void Add(ActorModel Actor);
        ActorModel Update(int ActorID, ActorModel newActor);
        void Delete(int ActorID);
    }
}
```

View markup:

```
<div class="row text">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-2">
        <p>
            <h1>Add a new Actor!</h1>
        </p>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 offset-2">

                <form asp-action="Create">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="MiddleName" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="MiddleName" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="MiddleName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="BirthYear" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="BirthYear" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="BirthYear" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="BirthPlace" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="BirthPlace" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="BirthPlace" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group mt-2">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-outline-success float-end"/>
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-dark" asp-action="Index">Show all</a>
                    </div>

                </form> 

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If anything else is required, please, let me know. I have been stuck hard on this for a while already, and if I am not able to fix this, I cannot progress with my other forms.

Like I said before, I tried replacing the `!ModelState.IsValid` with `ModelState.IsValid` and putting the executing code in there, intellisense suggestions and even manually, using break-points and I did manage to get it to work like that, but is not an ideal choice.

My knowledge in ASP.NET MVC is basic, so perhaps I messed up something or missed something.

Just for clarification - the called service works, i am able to post data, but if validation is present in the same method, i am unable to post anything and the button does not do anything.

Comment: If I'm correctly reading your comments - the view is already returned because the modelstate is invalid

Comment: @riffnl not exactly sure what you mean by that. when modelstate is invalid, it returns the same view, without posting data and saying to the user, that it has errors. if i remove it, i can bypass required fields and range.

Comment: About your answer - the modelstate was invalid so it returns the view directly - you never "saying it has errors" anywhere. But at least you fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the problem was not in the method, but the model.
`public  List<Actor_CinematographyModel> Actors_Cinematography { get; set; }` was somehow conflicting and not allowing me to post data. after making it possible to be a null value, everything works. not sure, why it did it, maybe i set up my database tables wrong. this thread is no longer in question :)